# How to set max number of tweets to fetch

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to set max number of tweets to fetch. The question was asked before but did not get answered. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

class listener(StreamListener):

 def on_data(self, data):
    print(data)
    return(True)

 def on_error(self, status):
    print status

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Comment: This link might help; http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/cursor_tutorial.html

Comment: You'd need to set up a counter in your on_data method, and once it reaches the limit of Tweets you want to receive, disconnect from the stream.

Comment: @AndyPiper I figured it out, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the solution. The problem was solved by `returning false` on reaching the limit by using `if and else`. The counter was initialized in the class `init method`. Hopefully, it will be helpful for others.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


#consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
ckey=""
csecret=""
atoken=""
asecret=""

class listener(StreamListener)

 def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.max_tweets = 200
    self.tweet_count = 0

 def on_data(self, data):
     global dataframe

   try:
    data
   except TypeError:
      print(completed)
   else:
    self.tweet_count+=1
    if(self.tweet_count==self.max_tweets):
      print("completed")
      return(False)
    else:
      decoded = json.loads(data)

 def on_error(self, status):
    return(False)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```